# Преобразование элементов массива с помощью регулярки

Tags: javascript

Дан массив - ["  2.7 ", " 5 dollars ", "13.5", 17, "9.5"]. 
Он имеет строки и число.
Любой элемент, который содержит буквы нужно удалить.
Пробелы удалить(знаю что можно использовать **trim()**).
Остальные элементы привести к виду "$13.50" "$17.00" - число 17 тоже конвертировать в строку с долларом и нулями.

Возможно ли с помощью только одного регулярного выражения получить это:
["$2.70", "$13.50", "$17.00", "$9.50"].

Если нет, то какой способ самый короткий?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Какой способ самый короткий?

```js
let arr = [" 2.7 ", " 5 dollars ", "13.5", 17, "9.5"];

arr = arr.filter( e => !isNaN(e) ).map( e => "$" + (+e).toFixed(2) );

console.log(arr);
```

Предполагается, что в массиве никогда не будет пустых строк или null (или они преобразуются в "$0.00")

`filter( fn )` берет функцию, вызывает её для каждого элемента массива. Возвращает новый массив, в который добавлены только те элементы, для которых вызванная функция вернула что-то, что в логическом контексте будет true.

`isNaN( any )` берет аргумент и пробует преобразовать его в число. Если получается, возвращает false. `!false` будет `true`

`map( fn )` - Так же вызывает переданную функцию для каждого элемента массива, и возвращает новый массив, где каждый элемент подменен на результат вызова этой функции. А toFixed(2) сам при необходимости добавит хвост `.00`

Comment: Отличный вариант!

Comment: Немного не пойму это место (+e)  - зачем возле элемента плюс ?

Comment: @Максим Метод `toFixed()` есть только у чисел (хотя сам возвращает строку). А унарный плюсик превращает строку в число. `Number(e).toFixed(2)` делает то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогли.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```js
const arr =  [" 2.7 ", " 5 dollars ", "13.5", 17, "9.5"];

const arr2 = arr.flatMap(element => {
  element = String(element).trim();
  if (/[a-z]/i.test(element)) return [];
  else return `\$${Number(element).toFixed(2)}`;
});

console.log(arr2);
```